# replace attribute not working in magento 2 mtf

Tags: php, magento2

I have  tried to use *replace attribute* in Magento 2.

As is written in the Magento 2 Developer Documentation one has to use replace attribute to override default or any variation set with your new one. One just has to give the path of his/her repository and use the keyword.

But when I try this the CLI is throwing the following error:

```
replace attribute is not allowed.
```

I have tried this in my custom module as well as in the Magento module, but it is throwing the error in both cases. Has anyone used this successfully?

The second problem is that if I use my module, and give the path of my repository, how is it going to identify which set is to be replaced? As it has the path of my custom module repository.

I hope someone can help me out.

This is the usage of replace attribute provided by magento documentation:

```
<repository class="Magento\Customer\Test\Repository\Customer"> 
   <dataset name="customer_new_default" replace="default"> 
       <field name="firstname" xsi:type="string">John</field> 
       <field name="lastname" xsi:type="string">Doe</field> 
       <field name="email" xsi:type="string">JohnDoe_%isolation%@example.com</field> 
       <field name="new_field" xsi:type="string">Some value</field> <field name="password" xsi:type="string">123123q</field> 
       <field name="password_confirmation" xsi:type="string">123123q</field>    
   </dataset> 
</repository>
```

Comment: do not down vote if you don't understand what i am asking  . i can make it more practical with snapshots.

Comment: Please provide some code, that you think can help with understanding and solving your problem.

Comment: <repository class="Magento\Customer\Test\Repository\Customer">
 <dataset name="customer_new_default" replace="default">
 <field name="firstname" xsi:type="string">John</field>
 <field name="lastname" xsi:type="string">Doe</field>
            <field name="email" xsi:type="string">JohnDoe_%isolation%@example.com</field>
            <field name="new_field" xsi:type="string">Some value</field>
            <field name="password" xsi:type="string">123123q</field>
            <field name="password_confirmation" xsi:type="string">123123q</field>
        </dataset>
    </repository>
</config>

Comment: This is the usage of replace attribute provided by magento documentation.
but unfortunately this is not working , i have followed exactly what they have mentioned in  their documentation.here is the link for their official documentatiion
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_entities/mtf_fixture-repo.html#dataset-replacement